# Windows 7 host for Windows 7 guest on Windows Virtual PC

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc

I have Windows 7 Professional (64-bit) and Windows Virtual PC (version 6.1). I made my virtual PC and I wanted to install Windows 7 Professional (32-bit, because I read you cannot install 64-bit on Windows Virtual PC) by using ISO file. I read that there is a danger to use the same operating system for both PCs (https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_disk_dualboot_sameos.html), but, because it was not clearly sad it is for all the cases, I tried and it was offering me something in the lines of burning the previous ISO, what I strictly do not want.

I cannot go lower than Windows 7, because I want to install LabVIEW on the Virtual PC and it does not have a support by lower versions (I have LabVIEW 2019 - http://www.ni.com/product-documentation/53409/en/).

I am stuck and I have no knowledge background of working with OS and there is no option for me to upgrade to a later Windows version for now.

Is it possible for me to use any other Windows 7 version (like Windows 7 Ultimate)? I really want to make sure I am making the right choice.

Thank you!

Comment: What you are missing is this "run that same installation of the operating system".  It means LITERALLY the same installation.  I have run windows from windows for many MANY years.  Also.. why VirtualPC? VirtualBox is free and has no limitation of running amd64 within amd64 (aka x64).  You will also have a VM that can be used in Windows 10 should you ever switch.

Comment: Windows 7 isn't the "right choice" for anything any more. It goes completely end-of-life in January.

Comment: In order to run Windows 7 within a VM, you must have a license to Windows 7, Windows 7 cannot be run as the guest OS and host OS without two separate independent licenses/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VMware article you linked refers to bouncing the same *instance* of an operating system between a VM and a physical host.  There is no issue with running a second copy of the same OS in a VM, nor is there a problem with dual-booting between two copies of the same OS installed in different partitions on a physical host.

That being said, VirtualPC is the wrong choice here due to its lack of support for 64-bit.  The best option is to use VirtualBox, which is free to download and use, even for commercial purposes.  It fully supports 64-bit Windows 7 guests, as long as the host is 64-bit and the CPU supports hardware virtualization.

It looks like you're trying to use software that interfaces with scientific instruments.  It's been my experience that these types of devices to not work well with virtualization.  Be aware that you may not be able to virtualize it successfully depending on the device.  In that case, your second-best option would be to dual boot by installing another copy of Win7 into a separate partition.